# Docker build does not proceed after finishing RUN statement

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to build a docker container (my first one ever) to set up a cross compiling environment for an embedded device.

I included a `RUN` statement that executes a script which installs the SDK provided by the  manufacturer of the embedded device. I verified, that the script finishes successfully with exit code 0 when ran manually in the running docker container.

However, during a `docker build`, the very same script prints its finishing message and then nothing happens anymore. The following `RUN` statements are not executed at all and the build does not finish. I have to abort the build process to get back to my shell. Can anyone imagine why this specific run statement does not finish properly, even when the executed script exits successfully?

The dockerfile in question:

```
# origin of the image from the official docker hub
FROM ubuntu:trusty

# adding the SDK into the image
ADD tgur-access-sdk-v0.9.0.tar.gz /opt/

# installing necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    make \
    python2.7

# create symlink for python to ensure that the sdk install script succeeds
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python

# Install the SDK automagically and delete the file afterwards
RUN /opt/gad-eglibc-x86_64-tgur-access-image-base-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh -y -d /opt/gad/R9.0/
RUN rm /opt/gad-eglibc-x86_64-tgur-access-image-base-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh

# Notify the user about the success
RUN echo "Enjoy your new Docker container"
```

The corresponding output with me aborting the hanging build after several minutes:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  379.8MB
Step 1/7 : FROM ubuntu:trusty
 ---> 02a63d8b2bfa
Step 2/7 : ADD tgur-access-sdk-v0.9.0.tar.gz /opt/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b6d032ec91e
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y     g++     gcc     make    python2.7
 ---> Running in 09bdccf10430

[..lots of apt-get msgs..]

Removing intermediate container 09bdccf10430
 ---> 12873d3e50ae
Step 4/7 : RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
 ---> Running in c1b8256e1fd0
Removing intermediate container c1b8256e1fd0
 ---> 166d5473a18f
Step 5/7 : RUN /opt/gad-eglibc-x86_64-tgur-access-image-base-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh -y -d /opt/gad/R9.0/
 ---> Running in aff8a5f102f8
Enter target directory for SDK (default: /opt/gad/1.0.0): /opt/gad/R9.0/
You are about to install the SDK to "/opt/gad/R9.0". Proceed[Y/n]?Y
Extracting SDK...done
Setting it up...done
SDK has been successfully set up and is ready to be used.
^C
```

Comment: To answer your question I think we should know the content of the (gad-eglibc-x86_64-tgur-access-image-base-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh) script.

Comment: it is a binary and thus not printable. It has a debug switch though, which does `set -x`. I will make another run and paste the output along the initial question.

Comment: I found a solution by myself while playing around. I added a `WORKDIR` statement to change the WD before executing the script. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue solved by adding a `WORKDIR` statement to the dockerfile that sets the working directory to `/opt/`. After that, the `RUN` statement finishes. There must be something inside of the install script that messes things up when invoked with an absolute path from inside the docker build environment (even when it works when invoked from a shell in the docker container). The final dockerfile now contains:

```
# Install the SDK automagically and delete the file afterwards

WORKDIR /opt
RUN ./gad-eglibc-x86_64-tgur-access-image-base-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh -D -y -d /opt/gad/R9.0
RUN rm gad-eglibc-x86_64-tgur-access-image-base-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-toolchain-1.0.0.sh
```

Comment: Stumbled over the same problem, but unfortunately the same approach did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem myself. Trying to install a Yocto SDK in a docker image. The script appears to be stuck after it completes. It turns out you need to be patient. I let an installation run sit while I ran an errand and I came back to a successfully installed SDK. Unfortunately, running with -D to enable debugging did not reveal why the installation takes as long as it does.

Answer (score -3):

There is a difference between `docker build` and `docker run`.

The `build` command is used to build an `image` starting from a `Dockerfile`, but an image does nothing by itself. You need to run it with `docker run`.

After an image is runned, it becomes a container and it can do what it is meant to.

The `RUN` commands inside your Dockerfile are used to prepare the environment for the future run phase of the container, so with the `RUN` instruction you need to install dependencies, and in general do everything needed to prepare the environment. Example:

```
docker build -t <myimagename>:<myimageversion> .
```

Once done this, you can run your image with:

```
docker run -ti <myimagename>:<myimageversion> bash
```

This way you'll end up with a console running inside your newly run container, based on the image you build with the previous command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not cover my question at all.
The RUN statement inside the dockerfile is needed to set up the environment which later should get started by issuing docker run. But that is not the question.

Comment: ok then your question is not clear at all. You are saying: «However, during a docker build, the very same script prints its finishing message and then nothing happens anymore.» That's how docker build works by design, and that's what I tried to explain with my answer

Comment: But when I run other commands during the build, even self-written scripts, the RUN statements are executed subsequentially until the `docker build` announces that it finishes by stating: `Successfully built d36c2e412129
Successfully tagged xyz:latest`